# Ansible Jinja template combined list into dict

Tags: ansible, jinja2

i am stuck with the template below :

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    test1:
      role1: groupA
      role2: [groupB, groupC]
      role3: groupD

    test2:
      groupA: role1
      groupB: role2
      groupC: role2

  tasks:
  - name: "[Test1] Mapping Role/Group"
    debug:
      var: test1.items()|map('join', ":" )| join(",")

  - name: "[Test1] List roles"
    debug:
      var: test1.keys() | join(',')

  - name: "[Test2] Mapping Role/Group"
    debug:
      var: test2.items()|join(",")

  - name: "[Test2] List roles"
    debug:
      var: test2.values() | unique() | join(",")
```

i prefer to use the format of the dict "test1" to construct the role/group mapping below

`groupA: role1, groupB: role2, groupC: role2, groupD: role3`

Actually, the result of the playlook is :

```
TASK [[Test1] Mapping Role/Group] **************************************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 21 October 2021  15:06:25 +0200 (0:00:00.021)       0:00:00.021 ******
ok: [localhost] => {
    "test1.items()|map('join', \":\" )| join(\",\")": "role1:groupA,role2:['groupB', 'groupC'],role3:groupD"
}

TASK [[Test1] List roles] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 21 October 2021  15:06:25 +0200 (0:00:00.030)       0:00:00.051 ******
ok: [localhost] => {
    "test1.keys() | join(',')": "role1,role2,role3"
}

TASK [[Test2] Mapping Role/Group] **************************************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 21 October 2021  15:06:25 +0200 (0:00:00.028)       0:00:00.080 ******
ok: [localhost] => {
    "test2.items()|join(\",\")": "('groupA', 'role1'),('groupB', 'role2'),('groupC', 'role2')"
}

TASK [[Test2] List roles] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 21 October 2021  15:06:25 +0200 (0:00:00.028)       0:00:00.108 ******
ok: [localhost] => {
    "test2.values() | unique() | join(\",\")": "role2,role1"
}
```

is it possible to do what i need with one line ?
thanks

Comment: sorry what you want  its not clear , confusion with your tests and test1 test2...could you precise what your start and what you want ?

Comment: Ok, i prefer to used the dictionnary with the format of the var test1 (roles are the key and groups are values and could be a list). I want generate one line like that : groupA: role1, groupB: role2, groupC: role2, groupD: role3

Comment: ok and your final line is a dictionnary?

Comment: no just a string

Comment: All of the above would be much easier if your test1 dictionary was more consistent with all values as lists

Answer (score 1):

when the logic becomes complex, i think its easier to use a custom filter (written in python):

you create a folder **filter_plugins** in your playbook folder (i have named the file **myfilters.py** and the filter **customfilter**)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {

            'customfilter': self.customfilter
        }

    def customfilter(self, obj):
        result = ""

        for r in obj:
            if type(obj[r]) is list:
                for s in obj[r]:
                    result += ', ' if result else ''
                    result += '{value}: {key}'.format(value=s, key=r)
            else:
                result += ', ' if result else ''
                result += '{value}: {key}'.format(value=obj[r], key=r)
        return result
```

---

use case:

```
- name: vartest
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    test1:
      role1: groupA
      role2: [groupB, groupC]
      role3: groupD 
  tasks:

    - name: transform variable
      set_fact:
        disp: "{{ test1 | customfilter }}"

    - name: debug
      debug:
        msg: "{{ disp }}"
```

---

result:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "groupA: role1, groupB: role2, groupC: role2, groupD: role3"
}
```

the solution is generic, with list or no list

same result with:

```
  vars:
    test1:
      role1: [groupA]
      role2: [groupB, groupC]
      role3: [groupD]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my above comment, I was sure that a simple refactoring of your initial `test1` dict to be consistent using list everywhere would made this very easy.

My goal was to answer with a solution not needing a single task/loop to calculate the result and to use some `json_query` magic in the middle.

This was before I (re)discovered that there is still an [unsolved issue](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.py/issues/179) and an [unmerged PR](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.py/pull/180) in jmespath which prevent to easily work with data returned as tuples by some ansible filters like `zip` or `subelements`.

This ended up being quite a nightmare but since I finally got the expected result with my original goal (no tasks or loop), I'll share it here. The solution is using several workarounds to transform what ansible returns as tuples to json strings, parsed back in ansible so they become lists that jmespath can finally work with.

The following playbook, using a slighly transformed definition of your original var

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    test1:
      role1: [groupA]
      role2: [groupB, groupC]
      role3: [groupD]

    q1: >-
      [].[to_string(@)]
    q2: >-
      [].join(': ', [[1], [0].key])

    my_map_string: >-
      {{
        test1
        | dict2items
        | subelements('value')
        | json_query(q1)
        | map('map', 'from_json')
        | json_query(q2)
        | join(', ')
      }}

  tasks:
    - name: Show result
      debug:
        var: my_map_string
```

Gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [Show result] *****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_map_string": "groupA: role1, groupB: role2, groupC: role2, groupD: role3"
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```